# Is there an efficient algorithm for shuffling array contents without memory allocation?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to design a function that copy a set of array elements onto the same array but in a different spots using another two arrays, the first one hold the indexes of the desired elements, and the second one the indexes of where they should be put.

So I came up with the obvious following code :

```
void Duplicate(int Array[],const int Dst_Indexes[],const int Src_Indexes[],int Count){
    for(int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        Array[Dst_Indexes[i]] = Array[Src_Indexes[i]];
}
```

Here *Count* is the number of elements and as well as the size of both *Dst_Indexes* and *Src_Indexes*

We can ignore the size of *Array*

There may be other cases to be studied along with the first one here, which is there can be some indexes in *Dst_Indexes* that happen to be in *Src_Indexes* also, and since it's the same array, a loss of information may occurs, here is an example :

Array = { 23 , 67 , 167 , 9 , 5690 , ... }

Src_Indexes = { 4 , **0** , ... }

Dst_Indexes = { **0** , 2 , ... }

First iteration : *Array* = { 5690 , 67 , 167 , 9 , 5690 , ... } (Here the first element was overwritten, while it's supposed to be used in the next iteration)

Second iteration : *Array* = { 5690 , 67 , 5690 , 9 , 5690 , ... }

Where what I actually wanted for *Array* to be at the second iteration is { 5690 , 67 , 23 , 9 , 5690 , ... }

While trying to solve the problem I kept away the thought of using auxiliary memory and I really would like to keep it that way, except when a swap is needed then I don't mind ( 3 -> 4 & 4 -> 3 for example)

*Array* can be of any type in the future, so bitwise operations are not to be considered

Comment: C and C++ are two different and distinct languages. You first need to decide which language you are using...

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed as lacking details or clarity: the OP is asking for an efficient way to implement his shuffling. The question may have different answers for C and C++, so maybe there should have been 2 different questions.

Comment: I updated the title for *clarity*

Comment: There is a [classic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) which everyone should know for easily and efficiently shuffling an array in-place, using no additional space.

Comment: I think you should decide between C and C++ ... the two languages could yield *very* different answers.

Comment: Unless I don't know what's shuffling, I don't think it is what I'm trying to achieve here, because at the end there are some elements that get duplicated and some that get eliminated @SteveSummit

Answer (score 1):

Your approach works if there is no overlap between the source and destination indices or if the order of appearance is such that no source element gets written to before it is used as a source.

Testing for this condition in the general case without allocating any memory or modifying the `Dst_Indexes` or `Src_Indexes` arrays has quadratic complexity, which may be more costly than allocating and copying the source elements.

Note that only the source elements need saving, not the whole array.

Here is a generic solution (in C, and assuming `Count` is non-negative) that allocates copies of the source elements using a `typedef` for clarity:

```
typedef int element_t;

void Duplicate(element_t Array[], const int Dst_Indexes[], const int Src_Indexes[], int Count) {
    element_t *save = (element_t *)malloc(sizeof(*save) * Count);
    if (save == NULL) {
        perror("Duplicate");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        save[i] = Array[Src_Indexes[i]];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        Array[Dst_Indexes[i]] = save[i];

    free(save);
}
```

A limitation of the above, in C++, is that `malloc()` does not play well with non-trivial types.    An option in C++, using a `std::vector`, as a buffer which will work with any type that offers appropriate copy semantics is

```
void Duplicate(element_t Array[], const int Dst_Indexes[], const int Src_Indexes[], int Count) {
    std::vector<element_t> save(Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        save[i] = Array[Src_Indexes[i]];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        Array[Dst_Indexes[i]] = save[i];
}
```

Even better, would be replacing the usage of arrays with standard containers, but that is left as an exercise.

Here is an alternative that will avoid memory allocation if all copies occur from an index greater to the maximum destination index so far using a linear scan.

```
typedef int element_t;

void Duplicate(element_t Array[], const int Dst_Indexes[], const int Src_Indexes[], int Count) {
    int need_copy = 0;
    int max_dest = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
        if (Src_Indexes[i] <= max_dest) {
            need_copy = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (max_dest < Dst_Indexes[i])
            max_dest = Dst_Indexes[i];
    }
    if (need_copy) {
        element_t *save = (element_t *)malloc(sizeof(*save) * Count);
        if (save == NULL) {
            perror("Duplicate");
            exit(1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
            save[i] = Array[Src_Indexes[i]];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
            Array[Dst_Indexes[i]] = save[i];

        free(save);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
            Array[Dst_Indexes[i]] = Array[Src_Indexes[i]];
    }
}
```

Finally, here is yet another alternative that will only allocate memory if the shuffle has more elements than a given threshold:

```
typedef int element_t;
#define ALLOCATE_THRESHOLD  (1024 / sizeof(element_t))

void Duplicate(element_t Array[], const int Dst_Indexes[], const int Src_Indexes[], int Count) {
    int need_copy = 0;
    int max_dest = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
        if (Src_Indexes[i] <= max_dest) {
            need_copy = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (max_dest < Dst_Indexes[i])
            max_dest = Dst_Indexes[i];
    }
    if (need_copy) {
        element_t copy[ALLOCATE_THRESHOLD];
        element_t *save = copy;
        if (Count > ALLOCATE_THRESHOLD) {
            save = (element_t *)malloc(sizeof(*save) * Count);
            if (save == NULL) {
                perror("Duplicate");
                 exit(1);
             }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
            save[i] = Array[Src_Indexes[i]];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
            Array[Dst_Indexes[i]] = save[i];

        if (save != copy)
            free(save);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
            Array[Dst_Indexes[i]] = Array[Src_Indexes[i]];
    }
}
```

Depending on the element size, it may be more efficient for shuffles involving up to `ALLOCATE_THRESHOLD` to always use the local array and only check for `need_copy` for larger shuffles:

```
typedef int element_t;
#define ALLOCATE_THRESHOLD  (1024 / sizeof(element_t))

void Duplicate(element_t Array[], const int Dst_Indexes[], const int Src_Indexes[], int Count) {
    element_t copy[ALLOCATE_THRESHOLD];
    element_t *save = copy;
    if (Count > ALLOCATE_THRESHOLD) {
        int need_alloc = 0;
        int max_dest = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
            if (Src_Indexes[i] <= max_dest) {
                need_alloc = 1;
                break;
            }
            if (max_dest < Dst_Indexes[i])
                max_dest = Dst_Indexes[i];
        }
        if (!need_alloc) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
                Array[Dst_Indexes[i]] = Array[Src_Indexes[i]];
            return;
        }
        save = (element_t *)malloc(sizeof(*save) * Count);
        if (save == NULL) {
            perror("Duplicate");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        save[i] = Array[Src_Indexes[i]];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        Array[Dst_Indexes[i]] = save[i];

    if (save != copy)
        free(save);
}
```

If you are using c++ and a type with default and copy constructors, using the local array may be costly and using `malloc` is inappropriate for the intermediary array.  Use the first or second approaches and replace the `malloc` line with `save = new element_t[Count];` and the `free` line with `delete[] save;`.

Comment: Rather than using operator `new` to allocate a buffer to `save`, use `std::vector` instead.   No chance of forgetting to release either, since it will be cleaned up at end of scope.

Comment: @Peter: good point! silly of me to keep using obsolete c++ stuff.  Can you edit the answer with the appropriate modern code?

Comment: Done.   I only provided a sample of a C++ equivalent of your first code sample.   There are other improvements possible, but I'll leave those as an exercise ;-)